# Where to place my database files and other important (configuration php) files on cPanel?

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel

I am new to web development and cPanel. Now I am developing a website which has a medium scale database and a configuration php file. I am using small business web hosting plan with cPanal and phpMyAdmin included. Currently I am developing my site using WAMP server installed in my own home PC. So my question is this.

When I am searching more information about my project, I saw that someone has mentioned;

> DO NOT PLACE DATABASE AND CONFIGURATION FILES ON LIVE & PUBLIC FOLDER. PLACE THEM ON DIFFERENT DIRECTORY OR USE HASH BECAUSE THEY STORES DB USER NAMES AND PASSWORDS..!

So, I don't know what is a "Hash" all about and all I want is to place my database and configuration files more securely.

Therefore, please tell me where to place my database files and other important files on cPanel and how I write paths between database and PHP files on different locations..? `ex: www.abc.com/db/...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the cPanel File Manager, the home directory, the directory you're in is the one above the `public_html` or `www`. Place your private stuff such as passwords and whatnot in directories there. **DO NOT** place them inside of `public_html` or `www` as this gives the public access to those files.

Answer (score 0):

You can find phpmyadmin in cpanel for databases